# How to use for loops in Django to create a table

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner at Django and I am attempting to create a custom table using a html template called `law.html`. Within `law.html` I have the following code.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Solicitor_Names</th>
        <th>Offices</th>
        <th>Addresses</th>
        <th>Primary_Role</th>
        <th>Secondary_Role</th> 
        <th>Other_Role</th>
        <th>Other_Role_1</th>  
        <th>Other_Role_2</th>
        <th>Other_Role_3</th>
        <th>Other_Role_4</th>        
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    {% for name in all_data.Solicitor_Name %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ name }}</td>
    <tr>
    {% endfor %}
    {% for office in all_data.Office %} 
    <tr>
        <td>{{ office }}</td>
    <tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

The output produces the desired table headings perfectly. Also, the `Solicitor_Name` column is filled with the desired data. However, I fail in my attempt to place the `Office` data in the next column. Instead, the data continues to populate the cells under the `Solicitor_Name` column. How do I format the code so that I can get my desired output that looks like this?

```
Solicitor_Name   Offices   Address
John            Orange LLP  123 Main St
Bill            Apple LLP   124 Bone St
```

here is my views.py

```
def law_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
 all_data = combine_data()
 return render(request, "law.html", {'all_data': all_data})
```

Comment: You need to do everything in the same for-loop. How is your `all_data` variable structured?

Comment: I have various functions to extract each specific data `def scraped_names():, def scraped_offices():, def scraped_addresses():` etc and then one last function that combines all data into a DataFrame `def combine_all_data():` I then imported this function into my views.py and assigned the dictionary {'all_data': all_data}. I will add my views.py to the question so you can see @gdef_

Comment: any thoughts? @gdef_

Comment: Could you access the name and office in one iteration? Something like `for data in all_data: data.Solicitor_Name.name data.Office.office`? Maybe what you should do is more pre-processing in the view, so you can access all values in the same iteration. Something like `for d in data: <td>{{d.name}}</td> <td>{{d.office}}</td>`

Comment: You need to construct the table row by row, not column by column. That means also that `all_data` should be a list of rows, not a list of columns. e.g. `[{'name': 'Mr. Shaw', 'office': 'Orange LLP', 'address': '123 Main Str'}, {'name': 'Bill', 'office': 'Apple LLP', 'address': '124 Bone St'} ... ]` instead of `{'name': ['Mr. Shaw', 'Bill', ...], 'office': ['Orange LLP', 'Apple LLP', ...], 'address': ...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to construct your table row by row, not column by column. That also means that `all_data` should be a list of rows, not a dictionary of columns (which it seems to be now). So you want to construct `all_data` like this:

```
[
    {'name': 'Mr. Shaw', 'office': 'Orange LLP', 'address': '123 Main Str'},
    {'name': 'Bill', 'office': 'Apple LLP', 'address': '124 Bone St'},
 ... ]
```

instead of like this:

```
{
    'name': ['Mr. Shaw', 'Bill', ...],
    'office': ['Orange LLP', 'Apple LLP', ...],
    'address': ['123 Bone St', ...]
}
```

If you're sure the lengths of your lists are all the same (it looks like it), you can transpose the second format to the first using:

```
all_data = [{'name': all_data['name'][i], 'office': all_data['office'][i], ...} for i in range(len(all_data['name']))]
```

or there's surely a function on `DataFrame` to do this (`transpose()`?)

Then in your template you just have one loop:

```
{% for solicitor in all_data %}
    <tr><td>{{ solicitor.name }}</td><td>{{ solicitor.office }}</td>...</tr>
{% endfor %}
```